# Camera switches off randomly with some apps

Tags: camera, samsung-galaxy-s-2

Samsung Galaxy S II running Android 2.3.3.

Layar: camera switches off about a second after loading a layer and stays off. App unusable.
Google Goggles: camera switches off and on rapidly in a loop. App unusable.
Barcode Scanner: camera switches off and on again sometimes.
Built-in Camera app: No problems.

What's causing this? What to do?

Correlations: this started happening this morning after I ran phone's battery dry yesterday, recharged it overnight, and installed Layar. It also crashed and rebooted once this morning when I tired opening Skype.

Comment: I too have similar problem with Google Goggle, CamScanner. Normal camera works fine though!

Comment: This question hasn't seen mutch attention in over a year, voting to
close as "Too Localized"